# LCD suddenly stops displaying

Tags: microcontroller, embedded, lcd, grounding

I am using a PC2002LRU-BWB-H-Q LCD with a STM32F4 micro and is powered through a TMP10424. There is also some 3V3 and 5V modules to. The problem is that the LCD is displayed fine for over days and then suddenly it stops to display. This may be down to power surges and thought the MCU was hanging. I added a watchdog to reset the MCU if it did hang.

The MCU seems to be fine because there is data coming from the UART and some Led's are toggling as they should but noting on the LCD. There is Light on it just no characters.

Also, I did notice that if I was probing the UART that it stopped displaying characters so it could be some sort of grounding issue, but the micro which is probably more sensitive is fine. I have 2 units set up so its not this particular LCD, the other one also stops displaying characters.

Is this a common problem with anyone?

LCD Interface:
[image]

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Not really a common problem. But the problem is that the display is used in write-only mode, so you can't read the status of it. What's worse is that 4-bit mode is in use, so any glitch on E wire will make the display to receive wildy different command and data bytes than expected, as the high/low nibbles are mixed. What might solve this is that periodically, like every second or every time the screen needs to be redrawn, it is properly reinitialized again.

It is also possible that the MCU write timing is on the edge of what the display can work with, so sometimes it might might just not see a write properly.

Comment: The re initialization does indeed fix the problem but does introduce a flicker. The pins are connected to the board via a joined back to back ribbon cable so this maybe a cause for some glitches. I am only updating every second or so that is way 4 bits are used. I may change to be read and write. Can useful data be read from the device?

Comment: Flicker depends on how you initialize it, so only initialize the bus to consistent state, and rewrite the characters. At least the busy bit can be read to know when it is ready to receive next data or command. Otherwise worst case time delays are always needed. At the same time you could also check if the address register contains what you expect, to determine if there were glitches during the update.

Comment: When initialized the screen is erased and then re-written, this causes the flicker. Unless it is possible to initialize it while holding the existing screen. Is this possible?

Comment: Well, why do you erase it then if it causes flicker? Why not just write the stuff that was already there without erasing it first?

Comment: I'm not deliberately erasing it. The initialize method (provided by compiler) does. By initializing it brings it back to its default value so it must be re-written. Now I haven't written my own initialization procedure but I would assume it may involve resetting and/or clearing registers and thus would clear the screen. Am I not correct in this assumption?

Comment: Ok, you did not mention what compiler or what LCD library you used. I was under the assumption you know what the LCD code does and how to modify it. Only writing to LCD is not enough here. If the 4-bit transfers go out of sync then it can't write those registers properly. Or maybe you can use the library to send the initialization sequence that will sync it. The procedure to go into 4-bit mode is similar in every LCD datasheet.

Comment: I will eventually probably write my own procedure so I have more control of what goes on under the hood. The compiler I am using is MikroC for arm and the built in functions are not visible. But even if I do this I will surely have to clear the device no??

Comment: I really don't understand why you think you must clear the screen before writing letters to it. Won't the display end up looking identical when just writing letters to it, without clearing the screen first?

Comment: i wont deliberately clear the screen but initializing it will reset it to the default. I dont think it would be possible to retain the screen when doing a reset.

Comment: The library just won't allow that. Don't call library init then, just send what ever LCD commands you find necessary to re-initialize it as you wish.